# Specifying Postfix queue lifetimes on a per-message basis

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to specify the lifetime of a message on the Postfix deferred queue on a per-message basis, or using some rules based on, for example, the sender address?

In our outgoing mail queue, we have a mixture of different classes of email, and I would like some of those to have a fairly short lifetime (promotional emails) but still have a long lifetime for most emails (operational messages, supplier notifications).

The only controls I can find are `bounce_queue_lifetime` and `maximal_queue_lifetime` which affect all messages.

The alternative approach, I suppose, is to simply have two Postfix instances with different parameters serving two queues. I was hoping to avoid the complexity but there may be no other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is all there is. You might consider using a different mailer which supports either different lifetimes (like [sendmail](http://rackerhacker.com/2007/06/14/adjusting-sendmail-queue-time-lifetime/)) or per-message queue management (like [Exim](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/exim_cheatsheet.php)) as a smtp_fallback_relay. This way everything that is going to end up in the queue as temporary undeliverable under normal conditions, will be sent to the defined mailer where it will be handled according to your predefined rules.

Comment: ironically, we've actually just recently migrated away from Exim (Postfix has produced a huge improvement in sending with a largish email newsletter campaign, although the new hardware probably helped too). Well, there are other alternatives too.